# How to restrict user to enter above 2018 in textbox using javascript?

Tags: jquery

```
<label>Year</label>
<asp:Textbox id="year" runat="server" placeholder="year">
```

To try enter this textbox to allow this text box only allow till 2018.thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify you want users to be able to enter a year greater or equal to 2018 in the Textbox or is it something different? (i.e. 2018, 2019, 2020, etc)

Comment: you can use max attribute of html

Comment: Why not just use a `select` with year options descending from the current? Much simpler to implement and zero input validation required

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have it in simple html we have attribute **max**

```html
<input type="number" id="year" max="2018" message="Year should be less that 2019"/>
```

Or in jQuery

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#year").on('input',function(){
      if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 2018){
       alert('Year must be less than 2019');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Year</label>
   <input type="number" id="year" placeholder="year">
```

Comment: What about if someone pastes a value in to the field?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Are you saying pasting is not working?

Comment: @mani. If is was useful, please upvote and mark as answer. If you need anything else, please mention, so that I can modify answer as per you requirement

Comment: Yes. If I copy the text `2019` and then right click the field and choose 'paste' the value will be entered without validation. In other words, always use the `input` event, not `keyup`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Very thanks for your suggestion. I have modified my answer, Can you check?

Comment: Don't use an inline event handler. All you had to do in your previous answer was change `'keyup'` to `'input'`. You will also need to convert the `val()` to an integer

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and don't forget to check the datatype too:-

```
<script>
/* code for jQuery */
$('#id').click(function(){\
    if($('#year').val() > 2018){
       //html message or alert box whatever you want.
    }
});

/*code for core javascript */
function checkYear(){
     var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
     if(year > 2018){
        //html message or alert box whatever you want.
     }
}
</script>
```